# php and file storage on windows servers

Tags: php, file, storage, download

My question is related to using a difference drive on a windows server to store files. The partition of the server is too small to handle a large amount of data files, and I want to use the D: drive as the file storage space.

My problem is, how do I access the files when they're stored on the D: drive using php? I've tried a multitude of different ways of accessing the files but they never work.

I store the filename and path in mysql and download the files based on their ID.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: On a side note, in linux it works fine due to the virtual paths that are possible. Is there something similar in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mount your drive in an empty directory residing inside your www-server / php-installation (for example `C:\www\datastorage\`)since Windows 2000: This Microsoft Knowledgebase [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

i use Junction utility http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx to create symlinks on windows.